# Doing http basic authentication in php

Tags: php, curl

I'm very new to php. I'm from a Java background and I wish I should do a Http basic authentication.

I do this process in `Groovy` like this :

```
def authString = "${key}:".getBytes().encodeBase64().toString()
def conn = url.toURL().openConnection()
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic ${authString}")
```

How do I do this in `php`?

Currently I'm doing with `curl` in `php`. But it will be nice if I can achieve similar thing without the curl option in php.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at this http://www.rooftopsolutions.nl/blog/223

Comment: @laxonline OP is at clients end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a $user and $pass, following code will do.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$pass");
```

Without curl you can do it using [stream_context_create](http://php.net/stream_context_create) function.

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("$user:$pass")."\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$fp = fopen('http://www.example.com', 'r', false, $context);
// read the content from $fp here.
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: He asked for a method without curl.

Comment: Yea. He also said it'd be nice to. So its optional. Whatever I have added that too. :)